# Why is there sound when things collide?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, energy, collision

My is there sound in this world whenever two (or more) things collide with each other?

Examples

- When two cars collide
- When something with enough mass falls from a height
- When small drops of water fall into the any water container

There are so many things associated with a collision; why is Sound one of them?

This question is related to Earth’s atmosphere only, not vacuum.

This question is for sound related to collisions only. No vibrations.

Comment: Your vocal cords makes sound without any collision. Same goes for all string instruments. Collision isn't the reason, vibration is. Theses vibrations cause pressure variations in the medium around it, which you perceive as sound.

Comment: You didn’t get my question. I am asking sound related to collisions only.

Comment: Collisions can cause vibrations in the colliding bodies.

Comment: @Mitchell so how does it result in sound?

Comment: You can look that up on google. "How is sound produced ?".

Comment: So there isn’t any other way of sound to be produced other than vibrations?

Comment: I suggest you to read the basics of wave formation first. That might clear a lot of things for you.

Comment: Like what basics? Which theories would be better?

Comment: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/u11l1c.cfm

Comment: *This question is for sound related to collisions only. No vibrations.* Sound is a vibration, and cannot be produced without something vibrating. How do you think you hear a bell, or the music from a loudspeaker?

Comment: Because there's someone there to hear it!

Comment: Regarding the comments, wouldn't it be possible to produce a sound wave from the pressure generated compressing the air as two colliding objects get closer to each other?

Answer (score 0):

when two cars collide, their bodywork very quickly crumples. the quick crumple can be though of in the same way that a drum head moves when struck with a mallet. the air near the drum head gets pushed and pulled by its motion and so does the air near the body panels of a pair of colliding cars. therefore, both of these things radiate sound through the air for the same reason.